# Ошибка пустого запроса к серверу

Tags: java, soap

Все делаю по http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
// SOAP Envelope
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("kris", "kristall");
//envelope.getHeader().detachNode();
// SOAP Body
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
// SOAP Elements
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("getBalanceByContractId","kris");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg0");
soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("488956");
soapMessage.saveChanges();
System.out.print("Request SOAP Message\n");
soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
System.out.println("\n");
```

И в логах томката пусто, рекуэста нет. О том, что отправлен пустой рекуест, с ошибкой отвечает соап сервер.

Должен такой хмл запрос

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:kris="kristall">
<S:Body>
<kris:getBalanceByContractId>
<arg0>488956</arg0>
</kris:getBalanceByContractId>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```